# Empty input field

Tags: html, angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am loading the data in a pop up window in form fields. When I run it the input area is filled with a proper string, but when I am trying to test it - it's empty ''. Service is not used during that testing.

HTML

```
<p>
Receiver currency Xpath:
<mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="fields">
    <input #toCurrencyXpath name="toCurrencyXpath"
    (blur)="update(toCurrencyXpath.value)"
    type="text"
    matInput
    [(ngModel)]="data.toCurrencyXpath">
</mat-form-field>
</p>
```

TyepScript

```
bank = {
  name: 'Nordea',
  country: 'DK',
  pageurl: 'http://n.dk',
  buyxpath: 'abc',
  sellxpath: 'abc',
  fromCurrency: 'abc',
  toCurrencyXpath: 'abc',
  unit: 'M100',
  id: 'abc',
};

it('should get receiver currency Xpath', () => {

const detComponent = new BankDetailsComponent(service, bank, fb, dialog);

fixture.whenStable();
fixture.detectChanges();

console.log(detComponent.name);                 //reads the value of the class variable

const currency: HTMLElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#toCurrencyXpath')).nativeElement;

fixture.whenStable();
fixture.detectChanges();

expect(currency.textContent).toBe('abc');       //Expected '' to be 'abc'.
```

});

Answer (score 0):

Instead of explicitly instantiating your `BankDetailsComponent` class, let `TestBed` from `@angular/core/testing` compile and create it for you. This is usually done in `beforeEach` blocks.

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { BankDetailsComponent } from './bank-details.component';

describe('BankDetailsComponent', () => {
  let component: BankDetailsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<BankDetailsComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ BankDetailsComponent ],
      imports: [...],
      providers: [...]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BankDetailsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should get receiver currency Xpath', () => {
     ...
  });
});
```

For further details, please consult [Component Test Basics](https://angular.io/guide/testing#component-test-basics).